# Converting an AudioStream object into a generic Audio Object

Tags: sound

I am attempting to record from a USB Stereo input and I want to preserve the stereo signal. When I tried to use `AudioCapture[]`, it compressed the signal into mono. When I use `AudioStream[]` followed by `AudioRecord[]` and then place the object in `Audio[AudioPlay[astream]]`, it generates a .wav file that is also 1 channel. Any ideas how to record the 2 channels in mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the function AudioRecord instead. Use `recording = AudioRecord[]` to get the AudioStream and then use `Audio[recording]` to create the audio object.

Comment: When I do that and check `AudioChannels[file]`, it still only gives me 1 channel. I have also validated that the audio input being used it stereo in a third party recording app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to preserve the stereo type signal when using `AudioCapture[]` and `AudioStream[]`; however, when using `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]`, the 2 channels of the signal were preserved :)!